# get mouse positions with pynput

Tags: python, pynput

I want to write a function that can get a bounded area of the screen by listening to the mouse and wait for 2 mouse clicks one for each of the corners of a bounded area on the screen, and return the coordinates for each point. I know how you can set you can set up pynput to act on events such as mouse button presses, but I want to enter a state where I listen for the event and then get its position.

```
def grabArea():
with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
pos1 = mouse.position
with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
pos2 = mouse.position
return pos1[0],pos1[1],pos2[0],pos2[1]
```

this is what I came up with but it just seems very clunky to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will hold a list of 2 points clicked.

```
def grabArea():
    points = []
    def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
        if pressed:
            points.append([x, y])
        if not pressed and len(points) == 2:
            return False
    with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
        listener.join()
    return points

positions = grabArea()
position1 = positions[0]
x1, y1 = position1
```